# Find the closest coordinate from a set of coordinates

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I have about 1000 set of geographical coordinates (lat, long).
Given one coordinate i want to find the closest one from that set. My approach was to measure the distance but on hundreds requests per second can be a little rough to the server doing all that math.

What is the best optimized solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you have "1000 set(s?)" which one is "that set" ?

Comment: A set containing 1000 elements. One element is a lat long coordinate. Ex: [44.4239734, 26.1504752]

Comment: Look at this library: https://github.com/darkskyapp/sphere-knn

Comment: By the way on Stack Overflow you are expected to show your attempts :-| This website seems to be more appropriate : http://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @procrastinator ok.

Comment: @stdob-- Thanks, that looks nice. I will test it out.

Comment: I dont understand. Why cant you compute the nearest neighbours for each node beforehand? Then the server just needs to return the values from memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use the ['Nearest Neighbor Algorithm'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_algorithm).

Comment: I would add some explanation and a link at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library [`sphere-knn`](https://github.com/darkskyapp/sphere-knn), or look at something like [`PostGIS`](http://postgis.net/documentation/).

Answer (score 1):

Why not select the potential closest points from the set (eg set a threshold, say, 0.1 and filter the set so that you have any points with +-0.1 in both axes from your target point). Then do that actual calcs on this set.

If none are within the first range, just enlarge it (0,2) and repeat (0.3, 0.4...) until you've got a match. Obviously you would tune the threshold so it best matched your likely results.

(I'm assuming the time-consulming bit is the actual distance calculation, so the idea is to limit the number of calculations.)

Comment: If the distance from any point is really big i will end up with a very big loop i think. Which will be slower than the distance calculation.

Comment: Agreed, that what was what I meant by tuning the threshold. If your distances are generally within a similar range you can pick a threshold that  will potentially include on average, say, 20, meaning you only make 20 api calls. (I'm picking arbitary numbers here.)

Comment: It's a little more tricky if the distance can vary greatly (ie for some scenarios you have 10 hits within a mile, for others all hits are 200 miles away). I'm also assuming that your set of coordinates is all available locally (say after one trip to the server). Once that's in memory iterating through that will be quick, it's just, as you say, the need to keep the actual distance calls down.

Comment: The distance can vary a lot, i need a small threshold so on so many requests per second on a big set will be really heavy on the server especially since this is just one step in what will happen there.

Comment: OK. I assumed that the set of coordinates is in memory, so the initial calcs to get the nearest, say, 10, would be very quick and not require any server round trips. When I've done this myself I just got the nearest locations by calculating 'closest straight lie' then performed the 'real' (ie driving distance) calcs against the server for this reduced set. This woked well and as it was simple was easy to test.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, i will try it out and see what fits best for me.

Comment: No problem; best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

### An Algorithmic Response

Your approach is already `O(n)` in time. It's algorithmically very fast, and fairly simple to implement.

If that is not enough, you should consider taking a look at [R-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). The idea behind R-trees is roughly paraphrased as follows:

1. You already have a set of *n* elements. You can preprocess this data to form rough 'squares' of regions each containing a set of points, with an established boundary.
2. Now say a new element comes in. Instead of comparing across *every* coordinate, you identify which 'square' it belongs in by just comparing whether the point is smaller than the boundaries, and *then* measure the distance with only the points inside that square.

You can see at once the benefits:

- You are no longer comparing against *all* coordinates, but instead only the boundaries (strictly less than the number of all elements) and then against the number of coordinates within your chosen boundary (also less than the number of all elements).
- The *upper bound* of such an algorithm is `O(n)` time. The lower bound may, on average, be `O(log n)`.

The main improvement is mostly in the pre-processing step (which is 'free' in that it's a one-time cost) and in the reduced number of comparisons needed.

### A Systemic Response

Just buy another server, and distribute the requests and the elements using a load balancer such as Haproxy.

Servers are fairly cheap, especially if they are critical to your business, and if you want to be fast, it's an easy way to scale.