# Find the closest coordinates "straight ahead", from a set of coordinates

Tags: javascript, gps, coordinates

I need to find the closest coordinates (lat,lon) to a given coordinates-point, out of a set of given coordinates. Similarly to this question:
[Find the closest coordinate from a set of coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40560949/522169)

However I also need to make sure it's  "straight ahead", on the same line
(with a certain maximum deviation of, say 15 degrees).

One way is to get the closest points - and then check the degrees between the origin and it for each and see it it's less than the maximum, is this the best way?

Answer (score 1):

when i work with gps i use OpenLayers so i don't know if this is a good prectice but you can use some OpenLayers features to avoid your problem

**https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getClosestFeatureToCoordinate**

like this:

```
import Vector from 'ol/source/vector';
import Feature from 'ol/feature';
import Point from 'ol/geom/point';
var vector = new Vector();

for(each coordinate that you want){
     var feature = new Feature({geometry: new Point(yourCoordinate)});
     vector.addFeature(feature);
}

var closestFeature = vector.getClosestFeature();
var closestPoint = closestFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
```

so now you only need to use something like this

gist.github.com/conorbuck/2606166

and compare with the anglee to where you are facing

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to make sure that the closest point is on the "same straight line", which is a restriction I need in my question.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I saw it before... this is the way I described on the question, still wondering if there is another better way.

Comment: I was searching about it i dont see another "easy" way to do it, there is some problem using this?